# SQL Query to get latest records for that user

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL database and I need a little help with querying the data from the table.

```
// Table
id              INTEGER,
column1         VARCHAR,
completiondate  DATETIME

// Sample data
(101, 'a', '2020-03-20 12:00:00')
(101, 'b', '2020-03-21 12:00:00')
(101, 'c', '2020-03-22 12:00:00')
(101, 'c', '2020-03-23 12:00:00')
(101, 'd', '2020-03-24 12:00:00')
(102, 'a', '2020-03-20 12:00:00')
(102, 'b', '2020-03-21 12:00:00')
```

Here, I want to view all the records for that specific user and display only the latest one from the duplicates found in `column1`.

Expected Output for user `101`:

```
(101, 'a', '2020-03-20 12:00:00')
(101, 'b', '2020-03-21 12:00:00')
(101, 'c', '2020-03-23 12:00:00')
(101, 'd', '2020-03-24 12:00:00')
```

I'm new with SQL. Would be great if anyone can provide any insight on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.id = 101
    t.completiondate = (
        select max(t1.completiondate) 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.id = t.id and t1.id = t.id and t1.column1 = t.column1
    )
```

Alternatively, in MySQL 8.0, you can use window function `rank()`:

```
select *
from (
     select t.*, rank() over(partition by id, column1 order by completiondate desc) rn
     from mytable t
     where id = 101
) t
where rn = 1
```

Note that, for this dataset, you could also use simple aggregation:

```
select id, column1, max(completiondate) completiondate
from mytable
where id = 101
group by id, column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one PHP-friendly way to do this, using joins:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, column1, MAX(completiondate) AS maxcompletiondate
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id, column1
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND
       t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND
       t1.completiondate = t2.maxcompletiondate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to join the tables max value to the current table somehow like this

```
SELECT user, `date`
FROM yourtable
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT MAX(date) AS `date`, user
  FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY user
) latest ON latest.`date`= yourtable.`date` AND latest.user = yourtable.user
```